# Creating a snapping UISlider in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uislider

I am trying to create a snapping UISlider in Swift with a simple line at each snap, and the issue isn't the actual snapping part it is the subviews added. The subviews added look like garbage but I do not know how to make so that the subviews are equally spread out at the point where it would snap? If you look they are slightly off

[image]

```
protocol SnappingSliderDelegate {
    func sliderChanged(_ value: Int)
}

class SnappingSlider: UISlider {
    
    let step:CGFloat = 5
    let start:CGFloat = 15
    let end:CGFloat = 70
    
    var delegate:SnappingSliderDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    func setupView(){
        //self.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "Play_black"), for: .normal)
 
        self.minimumValue = Float(self.start)
        self.maximumValue = Float(self.end)
        
        for i in Int(start)...Int(end) where i % 5 == 0 {
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: (Int(self.frame.width) / 11) * ((i - 15) / 5), y: 0, width: 1, height: 29))
            view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
            self.insertSubview(view, at: 0)
        }
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.width, y: 0, width: 1, height: 29))
        self.insertSubview(view, at: 0)
        
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    
    @objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider){
        let step: Float = 5
        let roundedValue = round(sender.value / step) * step
        self.value = roundedValue
        
        delegate?.sliderChanged(Int(roundedValue))
    }

}
```

Comment: "Looks better" is subjective. Can you describe exactly how you want them to look? If not, your question is off topic here.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, updated